# Jquery Ajax pass data between two forms

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a page with an ajax filled autocomplete field, if an extra addition to the autocomplete is needed, based upon the user selctind add new on the ('mainForm') I am popping up a modal form ('subForm') in which to enter the new data, process on the server using classic asp via an ajax post I would then like to pass the resulting data (two fields returned after a database insert, locId and locName) back to orginal form.

**Original form**

```
<form method="post" action="default.asp" name="mainForm" id="mainForm">

 .... rest of form ....

  <label for="locName">Location (autocomplete): </label>
  <input type="text" name="locName" id="locName" value="locName"/>
  <label for="locId">Location Id: </label>
  <input type="text" name="locId" id="locId" value="locId"/>
  <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub"  value="sub"/>
</form>
```

**Modal Form**

```
<form name="subForm" id="subForm" action="default.asp">
  <label for="nme">Name</label><input type="text" name="nme" id="nme" />
  <label for="pcd">Postcode</label><input type="text" name="pcd" id="pcd" />
  <input type="submit" name="sub2" id="sub2"  value="sub2"/>
</form>
```

The modal form is then processed on the server after an ajax submit. The form is submitted to a database and creates two values (id,name) - I'd like to to pass these values back to the original form into

**Jquery so far**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $form = $('#subForm');     
  $form.submit( function() {
    $.ajax({ 
      beforeSend:function(response){$("#locName").val("loading...");},
      cache:false,
      data: $(this).serialize(), 
      type: $(this).attr('method'), 
      url: $(this).attr('action'),

// this is the bit I need help with  

      success:function(response){
        $("#locName").val(response); // populate original form
        $("#locId").val(response); // populate original form
      },
// ---------------------------------------------
      error:function(){alert("error")},
      complete:function(){alert("done");}
    });           
  return false;  
});
});
```

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: What is response? JSON or plain text?

Comment: I could provide either - which ever is easiest to pass back into the form?

Comment: JSON, check out lauhub's answer below. I believe in classic ASP, you'll have to convert the string (as said below) to a JSON object after returned to jQuery. Otherwise, it's treated as a string. You might be able to change the doctype/content type of the form's ASP page.

Comment: Thanks Michael - Response.ContentType = "application/json" in case anyone was wondering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that 'response' is a JSON formatted string returned by your server (e.g. `"{locName:'Groenland', locId:'212'}"`):

```
success:function(response){
    //You need to first parse JSON data:
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

    //Then fill the original form
    $("#locName").val(data.locName); // populate original form
    $("#locId").val(data.locId); // populate original form
}
```